Will 12 foot 2x4s on 24” centers support 5/8” drywall
I want to add 5/8” drywall to the ceiling of my double wide mobile home. I am concerned with the added weight to the truss system.  I would like to install 12 ft 2x4s 24” on center from the outer wall to the center beam.  Would this add enough support for the weight of drywall?

A 4x8 ft. sheet of 5/8 drywall weighs about 70.4 pounds or 2.2 pounds per sq/ft.
If you sister the 2x4s to the trusses it can carry the weight easily and help strengthen the trusses which are commonly only 2x2s. ( If your trusses are built with larger lumber, it's even better.) As others stated, 24 inch on center is not a problem.
Bottom line is you should have no problem with your plan of 5/8 on 12ft 2x4s.

I can't speak to the truss system issue. As far as the drywall itself, it varies by thickness, type and manufacturer. Using the first 5/8" 4'x8' sheets I found at Home Depot, the specification page says 24" maximum spacing for ceiling or wall use, with the only exception when using double-layer for fire rating, and then it is 16".
